# Small Black Screw left inside microwave oven

Tags: microwave

The Service Representative left a small black screw inside the combination Microwave/ Convection oven after replacing a wire spring in the hinge to a drop down door. The screw may have been left under the glass shelf, which rotates.

The microwave oven is a built in wall mounted unit by Kitchen Aide with a matching conventional oven below.

The microwave oven was used several times prior to noticing the screw after removing the round glass tray in order to clean the microwave oven.

The black paint has been removed from the screw.

Questions:

1. Is it likely that the Microwave oven has been damaged?
2. Is there a way to check for damage?
3. Is it safe to continue using the Microwave oven?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We can't really answer this question here: this is a board about cooking, not appliance repair.  I suggest you try Home Improvement SE instead.

Comment: Appliance repair question; should go to Home Repair SE.

Comment: I asked my question because I noticed similar questions being asked on this site. maybe someone knows the answer.

Comment: Really you're gonna get much better answers on Home Improvement.  Also some photos with your question will help you there.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd sub-question, IMO, makes this on-topic as it concerns food safety, but I'll answer them in order.

1. Chance of damage:

It's highly unlikely, unless you can find any scratches which are cosmetic damage.   Small amounts of metal in a microwave more often than not have no effect, especially in the presence of food, and the effect of metal sparking in a microwave is rarely actual damage (sparking can interfere with the electronics in the microwave, but that generally just means rebooting it).

2. Check for damage:

Examine for cosmetic damage if you can be bothered and if you might want to raise a warranty claim.  The only other test possible or useful is to check that it actually heats the contents, which I'll mention below.

3. Food Safety:

If the screw is a leftover microwave part, it will be as suitable as any other part for being near food and potentially getting hot - so there's no food safety worry  from it.

The other food safety aspect is does it actually heat the food. If you've been using it, you've tested that.  If not, heating water in there will test that (to be on the safe side, don't heat a clean smooth container of water to when you'd expect to to boil, as in very rare cases it can exceed boiling point then boil when handled).  Failure modes are extremely unlikely to result in reduced power (as opposed to no power at all), especially in a permanent sense.

Answer (score 0):

A microwave oven is nothing more than a microwave transmitter. The cavity you put food into is part of the tuning of the microwave oscillator of the transmitter. Any metal inside that cavity detunes the oscillator but so does food.

Technically, detuning the oscillator can cause the microwave "tube" to heat up due to this detuning. However, it's a temporary effect with no damage of concern if it seems to be working normally otherwise. This is not a health or safety issue.

Potentially the life of the microwave is shortened ever so slightly but I've done far worse with transmitters in my career as an electronic engineer.